# jQuery plugin carouFredSel doesn't set proper size for a carousel after its initialization

Tags: jquery, angularjs, watch, caroufredsel

I'm trying to use the carouFredSel plugin for an angular application.
This application uses following dependencies:

```
app.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.event', 'ui.keypress', 'ui.bootstrap.dialog', 'ui.bootstrap.carousel','ngTouch']);
```

I initialized the plugin from a directive like this:

```
app.directive('slider', function(){
          return {
              restrict: 'E',
              template: '<div ng-repeat="links in linkstack"><a href="{{links.url}}">{{links.text}}</a></div>',
              link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
                  scope.$watch("linkstack", function (val) {
                      if(val){
                          console.log(element);
                          element.caroufredsel({
                              width: 600,
                              responsive: true
                          });
                      }
                  });
              },
              controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                  $scope.linkstack = [
                      {url: "/url1", text: "item 1"},
                      {url: "/url2", text: "item 2"},
                      {url: "/url3", text: "item 3"},
                      {url: "/url4", text: "item 4"},
                      {url: "/url5", text: "item 5"}
                  ];
              }
          }
      });
```

And implementation is quite simple:

```
 <slider></slider>
```

The problem is after plugin initialization the wrapper has wrong inline metrics however console returns absolutely ready "slider" element:

```
<div class="caroufredsel_wrapper" style="text-align: start; float: none; position: relative; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto; z-index: auto; width: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><slider style="text-align: left; float: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px;"><!-- ngRepeat: links in linkstack --><div ng-repeat="links in linkstack" class="ng-scope"><a href="/url1" class="ng-binding">item 1</a></div><div ng-repeat="links in linkstack" class="ng-scope"><a href="/url2" class="ng-binding">item 2</a></div><div ng-repeat="links in linkstack" class="ng-scope"><a href="/url3" class="ng-binding">item 3</a></div><div ng-repeat="links in linkstack" class="ng-scope"><a href="/url4" class="ng-binding">item 4</a></div><div ng-repeat="links in linkstack" class="ng-scope"><a href="/url5" class="ng-binding">item 5</a></div></slider></div>
```

After window resize plugin triggers update methods and then everything works quite predictable.
Please, advice where a solution dwells. Thank you!

P.S. The same issue was when I was implementing the revolunet angular carousel

This application uses deferred promises to display document body after authentication process, i.e

```
<body data-ng-class="{ready: isAuthenthicationChecked}">
```

CSS for the body is:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  &.ready {
    overflow: auto;
    .pageLoader {
      display: none;
    }
    .mainPageWrapper {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Well, solution was:
In css instead of 'display: block/none' I used 'visibility: hidden/visible' to avoid collapsing and directive changed also to provide proper delay:

```
.directive('linkCarousel', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
            return {
                template: '<div class="sliderContainer">' +
                        '<a class="prev" href="#" style="display: block;"></a>' +
                        '<a class="next" href="#" style="display: block;"></a>' +
                        '<div class="sliderBodyWrapper">' +
                        '<div class="sliderBody">' +
                        '<div ng-repeat="links in linkstack" class="item">' +
                        '<a href="{{links.url}}" onmousedown="return false;">{{links.text}}</a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>',
                controller: function ($scope, $element, $rootScope) {
                    $scope.linkstack = [
                        {url: '/url1', text: 'item 1'},
                        {url: '/url2', text: 'item 2'},
                        {url: '/url3', text: 'item 3'},
                        {url: '/url4', text: 'item 4'},
                        {url: '/url5', text: 'item 5'},
                        {url: '/url6', text: 'item 6'},
                        {url: '/url7', text: 'Ordinary item 7'},
                        {url: '/url8', text: 'item 8'},
                        {url: '/url9', text: 'Very special item 9'},
                        {url: '/url10', text: 'item 10'},
                        {url: '/url11', text: 'item 11'},
                        {url: '/url12', text: 'item 12'}
                    ];
                },
                link: function(scope, element) {
                    scope.$watch('linkstack', function(value){
                        var val = value || null;
                        if(val){
                            $rootScope.globalModel.ready.then(function(){
                                var $carousel = element.find(".sliderBody");
                                $carousel.caroufredsel({
                                    width: '100%',
                                    height: 'auto',
                                    align: 'center',
                                    fx: 'directscroll',
                                    auto: false,
                                    circular: false,
                                    infinite: false,
                                    scroll: {
                                        wipe: true,
                                        easing: 'linear',
                                        duration: 650
                                    },
                                    mousewheel: true,
                                    swipe: {
                                        onMouse: true,
                                        onTouch: true
                                    },
                                    prev: element.find(".prev"),
                                    next: element.find(".next")
                                });
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }])
```

Comment: Your watch function could still be running before the DOM has finished loading; try putting `element.caroufredsel(r.)` inside a `$timeout/setTimeout` or `angular.element(document).ready(...)` see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you! All those methods work just fine but they are not able to resolve my problem, because I'm forced to try manually time interval to trigger initialization (for me it was over 5000 ms). Seems like something is still processing even after my "slider" is fulfilled with child nodes from the controller scope and before its rendering .

Comment: Are your images really large/high res? Setup a JSFiddle our Plunker and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: I think that will be a hard contest to put my whole workflow into the Plunker because application is pretty big. Seems I know the reason of those issues. Application document body displays asynchronously after authentication procedures that are deferred promises but all angular templates are ready but they inherit zero size from body that is not displayed yet.